# Extract a pattern of attributes, merge and build a List with java lambda

Tags: lambda, java-8

I'm not an expert in Java Lambda, so I need your help.

How can I extract the following list:

```
[
    {
      "code": 1,
      "nestedList": [{
        "value": "A",
        "count": 1
      }]
    },
    {
      "code": 2,
      "nestedList": [{
        "value": "A",
        "count": 1
      }]
    },
    {
      "code": 3,
      "nestedList": [{
        "value": "A",
        "count": 1
      }]
    },
    {
      "code": 4,
      "nestedList": [{
        "value": "B",
        "count": 1
      }]
    },
    {
      "code": 5,
      "nestedList": [{
        "value": "B",
        "count": 1
      }]
]
```

To the following one:

```
[
  {
    "value": "A",
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "value": "B",
    "count": 2
  }
]
```

I tried groupingBy, filter, and other operations but nothing worked.....

For I'm using the following code:

```
public class MainObject {
    List<NestedObject> nestedList;
    //getters and setters
}

public class NestedObject {
    private String value;
    private Integer count;
    //getters and setters
}

List<MainObject> mainObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<NestedObject> nestedObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        NestedObject nestedObject = new NestedObject();
        nestedObject.setValue("A");
        nestedObject.setCount(3);
        nestedObjects.add(nestedObject);
        MainObject mainObject = new MainObject();
        mainObject.setNestedList(nestedObjects);
        mainObjectList.add(mainObject);

        List<NestedObject> nestedList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        NestedObject nestedObject2 = new NestedObject();
        nestedObject2.setValue("A");
        nestedObject2.setCount(2);
        nestedList2.add(nestedObject2);
        MainObject mainObject2 = new MainObject();
        mainObject2.setNestedList(nestedList2);
        mainObjectList.add(mainObject2);

        List<NestedObject> nestedList3 = new ArrayList<>();
        NestedObject nestedObject3 = new NestedObject();
        nestedObject3.setValue("B");
        nestedObject3.setCount(8);
        nestedList3.add(nestedObject3);
        MainObject mainObject3 = new MainObject();
        mainObject3.setNestedList(nestedList3);
        mainObjectList.add(mainObject3);

        List<NestedObject> nestedList4 = new ArrayList<>();
        NestedObject nestedObject4 = new NestedObject();
        nestedObject4.setValue("B");
        nestedObject4.setCount(2);
        nestedList4.add(nestedObject4);
        MainObject mainObject4 = new MainObject();
        mainObject4.setNestedList(nestedList4);
        mainObjectList.add(mainObject4);

        System.out.println(mainObjectList.size());

        List<String> listInteger =
                mainObjectList.stream()
                .map(mainObject -> mainObject.getNestedList())
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .map(NestedObject::getValue)
                .collect(NestedObject::getValue);
```

I was trying to extract the `values` and then get the `count` with another `foreach`.

I searched something like underscore.js. But I really don't know....

[Summarize array values, underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36532483/summarize-array-values-underscore)

Comment: please show your attempt to better illustrate your description.

Comment: Correct... fixing in 3, 2, 1..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the expected result, it's unclear whether you want to add the `count` property of all the objects in the same bucket after grouping or just the count of the elements in each bucket after grouping.

So I will provide several solutions which you can then decide upon the one you want.

if you want to group by `value` then sum the `count` property of all the objects in the same bucket:

```
Map<String, Integer> resultSet = mainObjectList.stream()
                .map(MainObject::getNestedList)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(NestedObject::getValue,
                        Collectors.summingInt(NestedObject::getCount)));
```

or if you want to collect the result back into a `NestedObject` type accumulated in a list:

```
List<NestedObject> resulSet = mainObjectList.stream()
                .map(MainObject::getNestedList)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(NestedObject::getValue,
                        Collectors.summingInt(NestedObject::getCount)))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> {
                    NestedObject obj = new NestedObject();
                    obj.setCount(e.getValue());
                    obj.setValue(e.getKey());
                    return obj;
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

if you want to group by `value` then count the number objects in the same bucket:

```
Map<String, Long> resultSet = mainObjectList.stream()
            .map(MainObject::getNestedList)
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(NestedObject::getValue,
                    Collectors.counting()));
```

or if you want to collect the result back into a `NestedObject` type accumulated in a list:

```
List<NestedObject> resultSet = mainObjectList.stream()
                .map(MainObject::getNestedList)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(NestedObject::getValue,
                        Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> {
                    NestedObject obj = new NestedObject();
                    obj.setCount(e.getValue());
                    obj.setValue(e.getKey());
                    return obj;
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: DISUS CHRUAIST... The second worked fine like a wine. Thankyou a lot man...